# Given matrix $A$, vector $y$, compute the orthogonal proj. of $y$ on $Null(A)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Given matrix $A$, vector $y$, **compute the orthogonal proj. of $y$ on $Null(A)$**

> $A =  \begin{pmatrix}
>         2 & 1 & 1 & 3\\
>         3 & 2 & 2 & 1\\
>         1 & 2 & 2 & -9\\
>         \end{pmatrix}
> $ , $y = [7,-4,-1,2]^T$

Well, here how I thought to approach this:

1. Find vectors that span $Null(A)$, lets assume we found $2$: ($b_1,b_2$)
2. Let's make a new matrix $B = Sp\{b_1,b_2\}$.
3. So we need to find orth. proj. of $y$ on $Col(B)$.
4. Let's use the normal system $B^TBx = B^Ty$ and from that we find $x$.
5. After we found $x$ we can find the orthogonal projection of $y$ on $Col(B)$ because $P_{Col(A)}y = Bx$.

What do you think about this approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is correct. In particular, you find the orthogonal projection to be
$$
B(B^TB)^{-1}B^Ty
$$